# Use Search folder in Outlook 2010 to search in multiple mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, search, search-folder

My Exchange email account has a limited quota so I move some messages to a local .pst file.

I created Search Folders that filter messages by specific categories, but it only locates messages in my primary mailbox. How can I create a search folder that searches through all messages, regardless of whether they're in the exchange mailbox or a local pst?

Comment: I see that in Outlook 2007, [according to a MS MVP](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/search-folders-across-mailboxes-t3546854.html), this was not possible. Though it was suggested that such functionality might be "on the drawing board".

Answer (score -1):

[Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) is a commercial product that indexes your mail in Outlook folders, PSTs, whatever, and gives you really fast and easy searching power.  I used the free version for a while (but it doesn't allow you to search PSTs), and a friend swears by the full version.  It does other cute things too, but letting you search your email is what it's best at.  I stopped using it because it was too much for my old laptop, but a modern machine should have no problem running it.